# How to fix "unable to resolve module expo module does not exist in the haste module map"

Tags: react-native, expo

Im developing a react-native application, i created my project with

```
react-native init MyApp
```

i imported LinearGradient

```
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo'
```

i got this error:

```
unable to resolve from "/Project/Nav/App.js". 
Module expo module does not exist in the haste module map
```

i tried to delete the node_modules folder and install all the package again but the error persist, i also clean the ios build folder but the same error showed up again

Comment: Are we good here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using expo when you create a project with

```
`react-native init MyApp`
```

The expo cli command is

```
`expo init MyApp`
```

make sure you've installed expo globally

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply, the problem is if i create my app with expo i have to start it from scratch since i use some third party!! is there a solution to import expo in an app created with react-native